# AWS EC2 metadata fetcher in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, recursion, rest, amazon-web-services

## Update

- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-instance-metadata.html

This seems to be the schema for the instance metadata, though the way they describe it isn't really handy for someone like me.

## Original Post

I wrote a tool to fetch all the EC2 instance metadata available under http://169.254.169.254/latest/ . Can somebody review my code and the underlying heuristics to tell if an output from a particular `GET` query is

1. a "directory listing" guiding me to more `GET` queries available down the path, or
2. actual metadata represented by the path ?

For example, if you run these two valid queries,

```bash
[ec2-user@ip-...snip... ~]$ curl 169.254.169.254/latest/; echo
dynamic
meta-data
user-data
[ec2-user@ip-...snip... ~]$ curl 169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/network/interfaces/macs/06:...snip...:e6/security-group-ids/; echo
sg-89...snip...
sg-84...snip...
sg-2e...snip...
```

your program won't know which of them signifies a directory listing and which actual metadata.

So my strategy is

1. assume every output line guides me to a new `GET` path and try to throw it to 169.254.169.254
2. if it returned a string whose first line is `{`, it must have been a JSON document, so do pretty-printing
3. if any of the child queries didn't return `HTTP 200`, the original query must have returned an actual metadata, so print it out
4. if any of the child queries returned an identical string as the last path component of the original query (with `HTTP 200`,) we're probably trapped in an infinite loop, and the original result must have not been a directory listing but an actual metadata. *E.g.*

   ```bash
   [ec2-user@ip-172-24-0-105 ~]$ curl 169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/network/interfaces/macs/06:...snip...:e6/security-group-ids/; echo
   sg-89...snip...
   sg-84...snip...
   sg-2...snip...
   [ec2-user@ip-172-24-0-105 ~]$ curl 169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/network/interfaces/macs/06:...snip...:e6/security-group-ids/sg-89...snip...; echo
   sg-89...snip...
   sg-84...snip...
   sg-2e...snip...
   ```

Show below is my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import http
import http.client
import os.path
import json
import pprint
import logging
from typing import *

ADDR = '169.254.169.254'
ADDR = '127.0.0.1:8080'  # SSH port forwarding
conn = http.client.HTTPConnection(ADDR, timeout=3.)


def join(a: str, b: str) -> str:
    return os.path.join(a, b, '')


def check(parent_path: str, filename: str, s: str) -> None:
    # time.sleep(.3)
    joined_dir = join(parent_path, filename)
    if s is None:
        return

    if s[0] == '{':
        print(joined_dir)
        pprint.pprint(json.loads(s))
        return

    file_candidates = [ l for l in s.split('\n') if l ]
    tried = [ (c, get(join(joined_dir, c))) for c in file_candidates ]
    if all(t is None for c, t in tried) or \
            all(c in t.split() for c, t in tried if t):
        # just a string
        print(joined_dir)
        print(s)
        return

    for c, t in tried:
        if t:
            check(joined_dir, c, t)


def get(path: str) -> Optional[str]:
    logging.debug("*** (%r)", path)
    conn.request('GET', path)
    resp = conn.getresponse()

    s: Optional[str] = None
    if resp.status == http.HTTPStatus.OK:
        s = resp.read().decode().strip()
    logging.debug("*** => %s", s)
    return s


if '__main__' == __name__:
    logging.basicConfig(level=logging.WARN,
                        format="[%(asctime)s.%(msecs)03d] %(levelname)s %(filename)s:%(lineno)d:%(funcName)s %(message)s",
                        datefmt="%H:%M:%S")
    check('/', 'latest', get('/latest/'))
```

A typical output looks like this, but I'm not even sure if I really recurse into all the available paths.

```
/latest/dynamic/instance-identity/document/
{'accountId': '...snip...',
 'architecture': 'x86_64',
 'availabilityZone': 'ap-southeast-1a',
 'billingProducts': None,
 'devpayProductCodes': None,
 'imageId': 'ami-4f89f533',
 'instanceId': 'i-...snip...',
 'instanceType': 't2.nano',
 'kernelId': None,
 'marketplaceProductCodes': None,
 'pendingTime': '2018-02-06T09:12:43Z',
 'privateIp': '172....snip...',
 'ramdiskId': None,
 'region': 'ap-southeast-1',
 'version': '2017-09-30'}
/latest/dynamic/instance-identity/pkcs7/
MIAGCSqGSIb3DQEHAqCAMIACAQExCzAJBgUrDgMCGgUAMIAGCSqGSIb3DQEHAaCAJIAEggHcewog
...snip...
FQCvZ++/XNsRExoPCHjmzzC2xKegmgAAAAAAAA==
/latest/dynamic/instance-identity/signature/
GjT4Lzh50Je9glKezoLw32/UnZC+VghBSVav8twUFXDFiEIcy+uwiPaEIWmzBVcR4QlVrknTXVGZ
ups/f9mLmUMoJbjb3ZEMWF4CiB0oUh7FNSUNh25KzMPb4sY15Ay7sDLR30uLJpQfJsUdR/T6nLBG
wYC9WdGlj3SNo+/tre0=
/latest/dynamic/instance-identity/rsa2048/
MIAGCSqGSIb3DQEHAqCAMIACAQExDzANBglghkgBZQMEAgEFADCABgkqhkiG9w0BBwGggCSABIIB
...snip...
gLVMLECQv+gesZ2j42MPDGFUJ1VzsRQg9mZkOc8AAAAAAAA=
/latest/meta-data/ami-id/
ami-4f89f533
/latest/meta-data/ami-launch-index/
0
/latest/meta-data/ami-manifest-path/
(unknown)
/latest/meta-data/block-device-mapping/ami/
/dev/xvda
/latest/meta-data/block-device-mapping/root/
/dev/xvda
/latest/meta-data/hostname/
ip-...snip....ap-southeast-1.compute.internal
/latest/meta-data/iam/info/
{'Code': 'Success',
 'InstanceProfileArn': 'arn:aws:iam::...snip...:instance-profile/admin-server-DEV',
 'InstanceProfileId': '...snip...',
 'LastUpdated': '2018-02-08T01:17:18Z'}
...snip...
```

Comment: Your narrative of the approach to making sense of the inconsistent behavior of the metadata service seems valid.  I can't comment on your implementation of it.  My solution was to assume response lines without a trailing slash were final destinations, and hard-code the relatively few exceptions to that rule.  Even though it is valid, you probably don't want to do the infinite loop and 404 detection in production because the metadata service is rate-limited and this technique means you'll be making almost 2x the number of requests you actually need in order to gather all the metadata.

Comment: You could make use of this library: https://github.com/adamchainz/ec2-metadata

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot "to assume response lines without a trailing slash were final destinations" Doesn't hold for the very top directory. "you'll be making almost 2x the number of requests you actually need" No, my code above does caching in a variable `tried`

Comment: @hjpotter92 Several fields seem to be missing, at least from the doc

Comment: @nodakai agreed about the top directory, but those are among the exceptions; the general rule holds. Also, I say ~2x requests because you are traversing one level deeper than you need to at each leaf, only to discover a dead end.